# Empty response from Rails JBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

There is the following jbuilder template:

```
json.extract! @order do |order|
    json.id                                         order.id
    json.room                                   order.room
    json.note                                   order.note
    json.order_status_id                order.order_status_id
    json.created_at                         order.created_at
    json.restaurant_order_items order.restaurant_order_items

    json.restaurant do
        json.id      order.restaurant.id
        json.email order.restaurant.email
        json.phone order.restaurant.phone

        json.place do
            json.title order.restaurant.place.title
        end
    end
end
```

I don't understand why but response is '{}'. So, I need to get a response like '{ id: 10, ... }'. How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: Does the answer work for you? If so, please accept it, otherwise please update the question with further details. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`extract!`](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/blob/ae05fc53fa01a085d599ffd900d5110471c1394f/lib/jbuilder.rb#L207) is meant to return only the named attributes, it doesn't use the given block.

```
json.extract!(@order, :id, :note)
# => {"id":1,"note":"test"}
```

Instead of calling the `extract!` method, you can also use the call syntax:

```
json.(@order, :id, :note)
# => {"id":1,"note":"test"}
```

With that in mind, you can start creating the template like this:

```
json.(@order, :id, :note)

json.restaurant do
  json.(@order.restaurant, :phone)
end

# => {"id":1,"note":"test","restaurant":{"phone":"123"}}
```

Notice that if the name of the resulting JSON key is the same as the attribute on the object, you don't need to mention it twice.

```
json.(@order, :id)
# vs
json.id @order.id
```